Nodriver click captcha box
I'm trying to click the Captcha box witihin nodriver in Python,
At the moment nodriver is unable to locate the chekbox anchor element, but is able to locate the iframe, which makes me think, maybe I need to switch window to it?
I saw examples only using selenium, there you need to switch to the iframe before clicking the checkbox. but in nodriver I'm not sure the option exists.
Here is a snippet of my code
iframe_element = await twitch_tab.select('iframe[title="reCAPTCHA"]')
await tab.wait_for('div[id="rc-anchor-container"]') # Error doesn't exists

